# 301 htaccess redirect forwarding to incorrect address

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to replace somthing in my url using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)kickass-sort(.*)$ $1sort$2 [R=301,L]
```

But this:

```
http://example.com/tags/kickass-sort/page3
```

redirects to:

```
http://example.com/Applications/MAMP/sites/example-site/tags/sort/page3
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/tags/sort/page3
```

For some reason the disk folder path is included. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either use a `RewriteBase /` before your redirect rule or use absolute paths in your redirect rule as this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)kickass-sort(.*)$ /$1sort$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

You should clear your browser cache before testing this.